What are the pros and cons for not using coping stone for the edge of a porch?
I have the porch represented in the below picture (right side in the picture shows the layout).
As far as I can understand I have two options:

Use copping stone for the treads (represented in the right side) and then start building the layout from that line up (the line represented by the top row of copping stones) . This is represented in the middle.

The other option would be to just shift the pattern downward and start building the layout from the edge of the patio. This is represented on the left side in the picture.


The red rectangles are the projection of the porch area (step not include) on the stone pattern, to give me an understanding where I need to cut the stones.

The question that I have is this: what are the cons when not using a coping stones at the edge of the porch toward the step.

I think it might be more of a design issue.  Unless the edge is not straight or the porch stones/tiles edge needs protection.

After speaking with the sales guy in one location I realized that you must use a copping stone otherwise you are going to see the exposed cut edge of a regular tile
